# Как настроить автообновление стилей css для пользователя?

Tags: html, css

После изменения css-файла страницы пользователя будет обновлена, если нажать <kbd>f5</kbd> или <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>. Но клиенты ведь об этом не знают. Как автоматически использовать за них <kbd>f5</kbd>?

Comment: [Здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502966/css-js-Как-указать-браузеру-что-нужно-обновить-закешированный-файл) обсуждалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно добавлять в конце ссылки на стиль немного произвольного текста и менять его при каждой выгрузке сайта, ссылка на шрифт будет выглядеть, например, так:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/all.css?v=eeded9c30610">`

Пример из  html-кода сайта ru.stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно генерировать папку с используемыми скриптами и стилями, где название папки будет хэш от измененных файлов.

Например: `//domain.com/assets/135adef13/style.css`