# Как запретить браузеру кешировать CSS стили?

Tags: html, css, браузер

Как правильнее и лучше будет запретить браузеру кэширование CSS стилей?

Comment: Заходите в инструменты разработчика, а дальше то, что на скрине
http://prntscr.com/j6i3wh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно сделать запрет со стороны сайта, можно добавлять динамический параметр к ссылке на файл css или js:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css?t=<?php echo(microtime(true).rand()); ?>" type="text/css" />
```

Тогда для браузера, при каждом запросе страницы, будет новая ссылка (которая будет отличаться от значения в cache) на тот же файл, и он будет его заново скачивать и рендерить.

Comment: влияет ли это на скорость загрузки сайта?

Answer (score 1):

Отлично работает вариант генерации. Подключаем свои скрипты и стили динамически, уникальным хвостом дописываются цифры текущего времени epoch:

```
<script>
    let epochId = Date.now();
    (function () {
        const pre_script= document.createElement("script");
        pre_script.src = "/js/myscript.js?t="+epochId;
        document.head.appendChild(pre_script);
        let mainccs= document.createElement("link");
        mainccs.rel="stylesheet";
        mainccs.href="/css/myccs.css?t="+epochId;
        document.head.appendChild(mainccs);
    }())
</script>
```

Это перед закрывающим тегом head. Для подключения скриптов в body можно пользоваться значением этой же переменной epochId.

Comment: Сейчас обычно на сервере добавляется. А, ну или хотя при сборке на фронте (я просто в основном бэкендщик :)).

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите чтобы всегда был без кэша

```
var date = new Date().getTime();
document.head.innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css?='+date+'">';
```